# PhoneGap android app icon not showing up

Tags: cordova

The icons of android are not showing up, the iOS icons works fine.

my xml:

```
<platform name="android">
    <icon density="ldpi" src="www/res/icon/android/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="mdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="hdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="xhdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="xxhdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="xxxhdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" />
</platform>
```

The files are all there. I used:

```
phonegap build android
```

Answer (score 4):

Try by copying your app-icon to /platforms/android/res/mipmap-xxdpi (each one - replacing previuos ones) .. rename your icon to icon.png before copying it

No need to add config lines to config.xml

This is the hard way but it surely works.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this in your config.xml

```
<icon src="icon.png" />
```

And place your icon.png in the project root folder where config.xml is,
make sure your icon.png file is 512x512

```
├── config.xml
├── hooks
├── icon.png
├── platforms
├── plugins
└── www
```